# How to set readPreference for MongoDB in Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

Anyone have success setting readPreference for MongoDB using Grails? I have tried putting a readPreference setting into the usual options closure in datasource.groovy but no joy.

```
grails {
    mongo {
        replicaSet = [<host1>, <host2>]
        databaseName = "plover_development"
        options {
            readPreference = ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()
            connectionsPerHost = 100
            threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 10
        }
    }
}
```

but I encounter an error when Spring tries to set readPreference and rejects the set as trying to write to a non-writable bean property. There must be a way to globally set readPreference but I have not found it yet.

Comment: I am using the [MongoDB GORM](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) from Spring plugin, btw.

Comment: What version of of the Mongo plugin and Grails were you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://jkuehn.github.io/gorm-mongodb/guide/2.%20Quickstart.html), I see the following example :

```
mongodb {
 replicaSet = [ "localhost:27017", "localhost:27018"]
 databaseName = 'test'
 options = new MongoOptions(readPreference: ReadPreference.nearest())
}
```

Try assigning your options settings inside the MongoOptions object instead of using the closure.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error "Error initializing the application: No such property: key for class: com.mongodb.MongoOptions". Since this doc is based on Morphia (I am using the MongoDB GORM from Spring) maybe that is why I cannot set readPreference that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to set `readPreference` at the collection level in Grails, which is the best way to do it anyway.

In the closure for mapping (e.g.) by calling the static `ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()` and pushing the result into a `readPreference` variable.

```
static mapping = {
    serviceTier reference: false
    linkedAccounts reference: false
    missions reference: false
    users reference: false
    name index:true, indexAttributes:[unique:true, dropDups:true]
    writeConcern WriteConcern.SAFE
    readPreference ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()
}
```

Comment: Did you ever end up find a solution for setting it globally?

Comment: I don't think the Grails MongoDB driver directly supports readPreference at all.  I searched for references to readPreference through the entire grails-data-mapping repo and found nothing.  It may be possible to do something via the low-level API though.

Answer (score 0):

grails {
    mongo {
        .....
        options {
            ....
            slaveOk = true
        }
    }
}

Deprecated, but you can use it